# Python: Reverse sentence and write it in another file

Tags: python

I'm trying to reverse the sentence and write it in another file but when I run it, it creates an empty `reversed.txt` file.

The following two lines are in file input:

> Hello World
>   How is everyone doing?

The file output will have the lines:

> dlroW olleH
>   ?gniod enoyreve si woH

My code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

name = raw_input("Enter name of file: ")

def Reverse(name):

    try:
        input_file=open(name,"r")
        reversed = "reversed.txt"
        output_file=open(reversed,"w")
        list=input_file.readlines()
        for i in range(0,len(list)):
            d = int(len(list) - i)
            output_file.write(list[d])
    except IOError:
        print("Cannot open file")
    except:
        print("Other errors")
    else:
        print("success")
    finally:
        print("prints always")
        input_file.close()
        output_file.close()
        #returns reversed

Reverse(name)
```

When I run this it prints "Other errors". It creates the new file `reversed.txt` but it`s empty.

Comment: Change the name of the variable from `list` to something else.

Comment: You have too much in the `try` block, making it very difficult to debug. Try separating this into separate functions: import, process, export.

Comment: If you actually catch and print out the exception, or maybe even re-raise it so that python prints out a stack trace, you'll have a chance of debugging it yourself.

Comment: You're not doing the right thing in the for loop. Try `output_file.write(list[i][::-1])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code snippet. But this should work better:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

name = raw_input("Enter name of file: ")

def Reverse(name):
    try:
        input_file=open(name,"r")
        reversed = "reversed.txt"
        output_file=open(reversed,"w")

        for line in input_file.readlines():
                output_file.write(line[-2::-1] + "\n")
    except IOError:
        print("Cannot open file")
    except:
        print("Other errors")
    else:
        print("success")
    finally:
        print("prints always")
        input_file.close()
        output_file.close()
        #returns reversed

Reverse(name)
```

Here we iterate over the read lines and then use the fact that strings can be viewed as arrays to reverse each line.

**EDIT**
By using `line[-2::-1]` we avoid having the ending new line at the start of the line we write to the file. Then we append the `"\n"` so that each line is properly separated by the new line character.

Comment: I don't think the question was about keeping the words order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
lines=input_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = ''.join(list(reversed(line)))
    output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: `reversed` is a generator; you have to convert it to a string first. Also, this will put the line end characters to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to tell you what's wrong, without improving your implementation (which is definitely possible ;) ) I'd like to suggest a few things:

1. **Indents are super important**:
   In your code just after the `def` you have a blank line. This means your function ends before it starts, and your `try` `except`s are just 'floating'.
2. **Your `excepts` aren't very helpful**: You just print small information when catching exceptions. You have no idea *why* the exception is thrown. A better way to do this is print the exception with your own custom message. Something like:
   `try:
       someCode()
    except IOError as ioE:
       print "Can't open file! - ", ioE   # Change to print() for py3.x
    except Exception as otherE:
       print "Unknown error! - ", otherE`
3. **Initialize variables you intend to use:** If you are using a variable, define it! Make sure any flow of loops/try-excepts will end up initializing your vairables. When in doubt, initialize as `None` (and check for `None` when using it). In your code, `input_file` is being used in `finally`. But if the `input_file=open(name,"r")` raises an exception, `input_file` will remain uninitialized causes another exception in `finally`.

Other than that your implementation can be improved from the other answers.
Hope this helps!