# Pickle isn't working and hence txt file created is empty

Tags: python, pickle

Write a program that defines a class Movie that has the following attributes: title, director, length (length of the movie in minutes). Create five objects of class Movie, pickle them, and store them in a file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import pickle
class Movies:
    def __init__(self,title,director,length):
        self.x=title
        self.y=director
        self.z=length

def main():
    movie1 = Movies(1,100,10)
    movie2 = Movies(2,200,20)
    movie3 = Movies(3,300,30)
    movie4 = Movies(4,400,40)
    movie5 = Movies(5,500,50)

main()

import pickle
try:
    file=open("movies.txt","w")
    fold =[movie1,movie2,movie3,movie4,movie5]
    pickle.dump[fold,file]

except IOError:
    print("file could not be open")
except ValueError:
    print("could not make list")
except:
    print("some unknown error")
else:
    print("successfully done!")
finally:
    print("printing always")
    file.close()
```

So everything works fine but the movies.txt file is empty. Im new to Python so I have less experience with exception handling. But from what I understood pickle isnt working.

Comment: `pickle.dump[...]` should be `pickle.dump(...)` - note the brackets. I have the same advice as per [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008271/python-reverse-sentence-and-write-it-in-another-file) - reduce the size of the `try` block. If you wrap everything in `try`, it is impossible to figure out precisely what is going wrong. Read [this](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/) on the bare `except`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the movie variables in the function `main` however they will not be present in the scope where you define your `try` block. Additionally, as have been noted in the comments of the question you are using the wrong syntax to call `pickle.dump`. It should use parentheses and not squeare brackets, i.e. `pickle.dump(fold,file)`.

Finally moving your `try` block into the `main` function will make things work as expected. Like this:

```
def main():
    movie1 = Movies(1,100,10)
    movie2 = Movies(2,200,20)
    movie3 = Movies(3,300,30)
    movie4 = Movies(4,400,40)
    movie5 = Movies(5,500,50)

    import pickle
    try:
        file=open("movies.txt","w")
        fold =[movie1,movie2,movie3,movie4,movie5]
        pickle.dump(fold,file)

    except IOError:
        print("file could not be open")
    except ValueError:
        print("could not make list")
    except:
        print("some unknown error")
    else:
        print("successfully done!")
    finally:
        print("printing always")
        file.close()

main()
```

There are still a bunch of style issues with the code, but this should get you going!

Comment: Which should make the program print "some unknown error"... Except that the code snippet won't even run because of a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: There is no `SyntaxError` from pickle.dump. There are plenty of objects that have a `__getitem__` method. Python doesn't know until it gets there that pickle does not.

Comment: @ramcdougal: you're perfectly right, my bad... I obviously need another coffee <g> - BUT the submitted code still should print "some unknown error" because of the `NameError` on the second line of the `try` block.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The answer should now make it clear how to get the code to run and produce the expected results. I think the original question had some formatting errors due to copy-pasting the code (not uncommon, and espescially unfortunate in the case of python).

Comment: @EmilH I fixed my code according to your editing, now it runs successfully with no errors. But the movies.txt now has a lot of weird text in it and not what its supposed to have.

Comment: @user1836292 pickle serializes the `fold` list and writes it and it's conent to file . It's not meant to be a text file read by humans, but a file that can be read by python to recreate the data that get's dumped. If you wanted to get a text file that you can read, then `pickle` is not what you want to use.